# Rails find or load specific record from includes on has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-7

Apologies for the terrible title!

#### Background

Users can have many Organisations
Organisations can have many Users
UserOrganisations is the join model and stores data about a specific user in a specific organisation.

```
class Organisation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_organisations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_organisations
end
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_organisations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :organisations, through: :user_organisations
end
class UserOrganisation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :organisation
end
```

#### Problem

I want to get all users that belong to a specific organisation, excluding users which have a specific attribute and including or eager loading the joining UserOrganisation record.

At the moment I'm calling

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  scope :super_users, -> { where(super_user: true) }
end

@organistion.users.excluding(User.super_users)
```

I want to be able to reference values from the specific `UserOrganistion.where(user_id: user.id, organisation_id: @organistion.id)`

Is there a way of doing it this way around or do I need to do `@organisation.user_organisations.joins(:users).merge(User.not_super_users)`

Comment: If what you want is the records from the join table `user_organisations` then yes you want `@organisation.user_organisations`. On a side note I would use a more descriptive name like `Membership` or `Position` - A + B is just a very lazy convention. The code would make a whole lot more sense when you do `@organization.memberships`.

Comment: @max Naming things is hard but you're right. ...this is going to be a good refactor!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want do something like this:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
JOIN user_organisations uo ON u.id = uo.user_id
JOIN organisations o ON o.id = uo.organisation_id
WHERE o.id = some_organisation_id
AND u.super_admin = false
```

and the equivalent AR query can be:

```
Organisation.find_by(id: some_organisation_id).users.where(admin: false)
```

or

```
Organisation.find_by(id: some_organisation_id).users.where.not(admin: true)
```